# rsync with delta transfers to synchronize based on timestamps

Tags: rsync

I use rsync command to delta transfers. What rsync does is that it would transfer only changes. Now I have two machines each of which have two folders whose contents get changed from time to time. What I want is to have a script that when executed replaces the contents of the side that is older with the one that is newer. The older one is the one that has lower timestamp when compared with the newer one. Is rsync capable of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-u` option (which won't overwrite a file with a newer timestamp) and run `rsync` twice:

```
local@localhost: rsync -au remote@remotehost:/dir1/ dir2
local@localhost: rsync -au dir2/ remote@remotehost:/dir1
```

Answer (score -1):

Duplicates:
[synchronization-of-a-directory-in-2-systems-using-rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/316201/synchronization-of-a-directory-in-2-systems-using-rsync)